# Why do created_at/updated_at get created when migration does not have timestamps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 3.2 with the following migration and created_at/updated_at both get generated.  I was under the impression that adding t.timestamps was what caused those columns to get generated.

```
class CreateContactsCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts_countries do |t|
      t.string :name, :official_name, :null => false
      t.string :alpha_2_code, :null => false, :limit => 2
      t.string :alpha_3_code, :null => false, :limit => 3
    end

    add_index :contacts_countries, :alpha_2_code
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and when I removed t.timestamps and ran the migration it didn't create the created_at and updated at fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delete the table and check again becuase

```
By default, the generated migration will include t.timestamps (which creates 
the updated_at and created_at columns that are automatically populated 
by Active Record).
```

Ref [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-model)

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I dropped the table and reran the migration and the timestamps were not present. Not sure what happened the first time around. Probably an oversight on my end